# SQL view on table to combine rows into additional columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-view

This has stumped me a little, I have a table like this

| Id | Address | Address 1 | Postcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 straight street | 4 corners | BL51 ANK |
| 1 | 46 Double Close | Some Place | ZE12 7TB |
| 2 | 7 The Fields | Farmland | FA7 5ME |

I need to create a view that will produce this result:

| Id | Address | Address 1 | Postcode | Address | Address 1 | Postcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 straight street | 4 corners | BL51 ANK | 46 Double Close | Some Place | ZE12 7TB |
| 2 | 7 The Fields | Farmland | FA7 5ME |  |  |  |

So basically based on the ID there can be between 4 and 50 rows, I need this returning as a single row with multiple columns containing the different data. I didn't want to do 50 joins as I'm sure there is a smarter way to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: Would each `Id` always have at most 2 records?  What is the logic which determines which address goes on the left?

Comment: SQL Server 2016.
The Id can have up to 50 records and is the unique identifier for a company, that company can have up to 50 addresses. We need to feed this into some OCR software and they need it manipulating into the 1 row with multiple columns.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to join x 50 times but was really repetitive and was hoping there was better way. I tried looking at the aggregation but again there wasn't a lot of difference between that and a join. So looking for some pointers on how to do it. Searching this site I can see some examples, but nothing that related to this use case with 1 table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation (or `pivot`).  Simpler and faster than 50 joins, but still cumbersome:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then address end),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then address1 end),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then postcode end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then address end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then address1 end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then postcode end),
       . . .
       max(case when seqnum = 50 then address end),
       max(case when seqnum = 50 then address1 end),
       max(case when seqnum = 50 then postcode end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

The code is pretty repetitive, so it is simple to generate it in a spreadsheet.